# ASP.NET MVC View - cannot access System.Data.Linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there any reason the namespace `linq` does not appear in system.data when I am in my view in `asp.net MVC`?

I can access the namespace fine in my code...

**EDIT**:

**I realize this is not good design, I'm just curious**

Comment: Inline queries in an MVC view?  Step away from the compiler...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.Linq" %>`

But, why do you even need LINQ in your view? You might want to consider keeping the logic you need in a HtmlHelper or your controller.

Comment: tried to import the namespace, however it says the namespace 'linq' doesn't exist in 'system.data' !

Comment: @benpage - Is System.Data.Linq referenced in your project?  Note:  I have agree with this answer, you shouldn't have anything that needs linq here...

Comment: @nick - yes it is indeed referenced, hence i can access it in my code

Answer (score 5):

You may need to add an assembly reference in your project web.config file if it's not there:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        </assemblies>
    </compilation>
</system.web>
```